# SQL- deleting rows with specific period

Tags: sql

I am trying to delete certain rows from a temp table, where the period is <= 201701. But it should not delete if the period range is > 201712 (including 201712 and less).

```
+---------+---------+--------+--------+
| fundsrc | project | period | amount |
+---------+---------+--------+--------+
| F123    | P1      | 201712 |     23 |
| F123    | P2      | 201712 |     24 |
| F9382   | P1      | 201712 |    883 |
| F9382   | P1      | 201801 |    567 |
| F9832   | P4      | 201809 |    372 |
+---------+---------+--------+--------+
```

As in the attached image, the delete query should remove only the green rows and leave the others.

I tried this query, but this doesn't seems to be working the way I want-

```sql
delete from TABLE where NOT(period >= 201801) and period <= 201712
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Its a different platform for the ERP we use. Its called RERX. But it behaves in the same way as SQL server

Comment: In the first 3 rows the period is 201712.  Is that correct?  Should funsrc=F123 have period 201701 instead?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Basically if for a particular fundsrc, the max period is 201712, then those rows should be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to delete all rows for a `fundsrc` where no row later than 201712 exists:

```
select from t
   where not exists (select 1
                     from t t2
                     where t2.fundsrc = t.fundsrc and
                           t2.period > 201712
                    );
```

In SQL Server, you can also do this using an updatable CTE:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, max(period) over (partition by fundsrc) as max_period
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where max_period <= 201712;
```